# Im trying to understand why this case is always going off

Tags: go, select, concurrency

I'm trying to understand why in this `select` statement the first case always goes off and does not wait for the channel to be filled. For this program I'm trying to get the program to wait till all the channels have been filled and whenever a channel is filled by the method it is put in the first available space in the array of channels

I tried putting the line `<-res[i]` in the case statement but for some reason this case always goes off regardless of whether or not the channels have a value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "time"

)

func numbers(sz int) (res chan float64) {
    res = make(chan float64)
    go func() {
        defer close(res) 
        num := 0.0
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1000)) *time.Microsecond)
        for i := 0; i < sz; i++ {
            num += math.Sqrt(math.Abs(rand.Float64()))
        }
        num /= float64(sz)
        res <- num
        return
    }()
    return
}

func main() {
    var nGo int
    rand.Seed(42)
    fmt.Print("Number of Go routines: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d \n", &nGo)
    res := make([]chan float64, nGo)
    j:=0
    for i := 0; i < nGo; i++ {  
        res[i] =numbers(1000)
    }
    for true{
        for i := 0; i < nGo;  {
            select {
                case <-res[i]:{
                    res[j]=res[i]//this line
                    j++
                }
                default:
                i++



            }
        }
        if j==nGo{
            break 
        }
    }

        fmt.Println(<-res[nGo-1])


}
```

The print line should print some float.

Answer (score 1):

> `<-res[i]` in the case statement but for some reason this case always goes off regarless of wether or not the channels has a value

It will only *not* choose this case if the channel's buffer is full (i.e. a value cannot be sent without blocking). Your channel has a buffer length equal to the number of values you're sending on it, so it will never block, giving it no reason to ever take the `default` case.

Comment: O I see what your saying is it at all possible to get the case to go off only when a channel in the buffer has a value. What I mean is the moment a value is in the channel it calls that case otherwise it calls the default cause and increase i.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but if you want it to take the `default` case if there is already a single value in the channel, use an unbuffered channel or a channel with a buffer length of 1 instead of setting the buffer length to `nGo`.

Comment: I tried using an unbuffered channel and got this error "missing len argument to make([]chan float64)" so i put it to 1 but it still for some reason causes an index out of bounds and I checked the default case is never reached. It just keeps enetering in the first cause until "j" is greater than the index of the array